# Solving a non-linear system of trigonometric equations

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I run into a problem of non-linear system that involve trigonometric components. I need advise to solve then analytically for [x,y]. The equations are

\begin{align}
  & F={{k}_{l}}x+{{k}_{d}}(\sqrt{{{(l+x)}^{2}}+{{(w-y)}^{2}}}-\sqrt{{{l}^{2}}+{{w}^{2}}})\cos\theta  \\ 
 & {{k}_{w}}y={{k}_{d}}(\sqrt{{{(l+x)}^{2}}+{{(w-y)}^{2}}}-\sqrt{{{l}^{2}}+{{w}^{2}}})\sin\theta  \\ 
 & \theta =\arctan \frac{w-y}{l+x} \\ 
\end{align}

It is actually simple physic problem of force equilibrium. The structure of 2D springs as rectangle as shown in the picture is extend with force $F$  in each corner. Therefore two spring $k_l$ are extended by distance $x$. Two spring $k_w$ are compressed by length $y$.
[2D spring structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gk456.jpg)

Comment: I would forgo the trig and work directly in Euclidean coordinates -- the angle $\theta$ depends on the two extensions and so is not doing you any favors here

Comment: It's true. I just think that it might get easier with trig. Anyway, I could not solve in Euclidean coordinates either. The x and y term are not separated. I can not do either elimination or substitution.

Comment: It seems the following. We can get rid of $\theta$, provided the following transformations are admissible and considered degenerated cases separately. Indeed, we have 
$\tan\theta=\frac{w-y}{l+x}=\frac {k_\omega y}{F-k_l x}$ and 
$(F-k_l x)^2+ k_\omega^2y^2=k_d^2 (\sqrt{{{(l+x)}^{2}}+{{(w-y)}^{2}}}-\sqrt{{{l}^{2}}+{{w}^{2}}})^2$.